# How to debug/verify a codeless kext for USB CDC device?

Tags: macos, usb, kernel, kernel-extension

I created a Codeless kext for an USB CDC device, to prevent it from being listed within the network settings.

According to kextutil, the kext is valid (besides the warning that it is self-signed).

When I load it with kextutil, the log file shows warning about the kext's invalid signature.

Now I want to verify, that it is properly loaded and used whenever my device is plugged in. To do that I set the IOKitDebug to the maximum value (65535). The only output I see in the console is:

```
02/09/14 14:57:59,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBCDCACMData: Version number - 4.2.1b5, Input buffers 8, Output buffers 16
02/09/14 14:57:59,000 kernel[0]: AppleUSBCDC: Version number - 4.2.1b5
```

No reference to my kext (com.foo.my-device.kext).

The Info.plist below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.foo.my-device.kext</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>SerialHelper</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>KEXT</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>MSP Tools Driver</key>
        <dict>
            <key>IOKitDebug</key>
            <integer>65535</integer>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>AppleUSBCDC</string>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOUSBDevice</string>
            <key>IOProviderMergeProperties</key>
            <dict>
                <key>HiddenPort</key>
                <string>1</string>
            </dict>
            <key>idProduct</key>
            <integer>YYYYY</integer>
            <key>idVendor</key>
            <integer>XXXXX</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>OSBundleRequired</key>
    <string>Root</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Isn't it working as expected since it's not referenced? Also, `YYYYY` nor `XXXXX` are valid id integers.

Comment: I can't tell if it is referenced/working or not. There are no useful debug messages in the Console. XXXXX and YYYYY are placeholders for the real values of the real USB device.

Comment: A codeless kext’s IOKitPersonalities dictionary names other kexts that are loaded when a personality matches on a device. Each of these other kexts must have an executable.

Comment: So I set CFBundleIdentifier to the name of the kext I want to use for the given device? As I have a USB CDC device, the value com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC should be correct, right?

Comment: I set mine up slightly different, using `com.apple.kernel.iokit`, which tends to be more generic. [*info*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Families/Families.html). Try using the [I/O Registry Explorer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/TheRegistry/TheRegistry.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000014-TP9) also, it can prove to be helpful for this.